# Does zerobrane v1.9 support UTF-8 encoding now？

Tags: utf-8, zerobrane

I wrote a Lua script with zerobrane, which can run in the editor, but it has a utf8 encoding error when it is called and executed by other languages, such as python. So, how should I set it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the code of the script you wrote.
To help people to answer you please have a look at this advice to write a good question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the IDE provides full UTF-8 support (in the editor). If your script returns results that are non-UTF-8 encoded, you may specify the codepage you are using to convert (see the `codepage` setting in the [documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#general)).

I'm not sure what "encoding error" you are referring to, so the a script sample and some description of your setup may help.